# xPages Ext Lib ViewController

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I've found this interesting bit of code [link](https://svn-166.openntf.org/svn/xpages/extlib/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib.group/src/com/ibm/xsp/extlib/data/ViewController.java) which implements a ViewController in the the Extension Library.

How can a programmer access this class from a managed bean.  I have the Extension Library (8.5.2) installed. But com.ibm.xsp.extlib.data.ViewController can't be resolved.  I may be in over my head here, but willing to take a plunge.

Thanks,

-- Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on Project in Java perspective/Package Explorer view. Use Build Path\Configure Build Path... menu. Use fourth tab Order and Export. Tick Plug-in Dependencies item. Now you will get access to ExtLib classes in Java code.

Unfortunately, class you found sources for is not part of the ExtLib distribution (package `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.group`), so you won't find it.